# Disable the error message box while loading an external movie with actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a compiled **swf** file and a I **can't edit it**, but the movie is working fine (but gives an error message with a message box).

I am using it from an other movie (load with as3 code).
When the loader movie loads it the error message box appears.

**I wonder is it possible to disable the errors while loading a movie with as3.**

Here is the error in the message box:

```
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at motionsound11_fla::_all_29/motionsound11_fla::frame249()"
```

---

Yes. Here is the error message (editted my first post):

```
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at motionsound11_fla::_all_29/motionsound11_fla::frame249()"
```

And I don't want to decompile my movie. It becomes more complex when decompiled. Yes, for understanding the problem I did. But my first problem is disable the error message box.

Thanks so much.

---

Yes, You are right. 
There is no error in a browser (with flash player plugin).
My project wont be in a browser. It will be an executable file (.exe) or .swf . So people who have "Adobe Flash CS3" on their computers will see the error in swf format file.

(i will add this information to my question : " The loader wont be on a web page. It will be used as .swf file or executable file" )

**And your answer is acceptable. I will publish as html page not .exe or .swf. This will be more secure,dynamic and has no platform dependence.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but I'm not sure the release version of Flash player plugin would produce an error like that - are you running this in the debug plugin? What you could do is test on a box you know has never been used for development - it's possible the error simply won't appear when you deploy your application.

That said, any Flash developers who use your app might still see it!

Comment: The loader wont be on a web page. It will be used as .swf file or executable file

Comment: Now i decide to publish as web page. This way, the project will be more secure and dynamic. Thanks